# What does it mean to say "tensors transform sensibly"?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, terminology, notation

I have been reading about tensors and they are described as "objects which transform in a physically meaningful/sensible manner" and obey the equation (for rank 2, but generalises) $T'_{ij}=R_{ip}R_{jq}T_{pq}$. I am struggling to understand why this equation makes $T_{ij}$ that it is physically meaningful. I think part of my misunderstanding comes from not getting what $T_{ij}'$ is. If I change basis then the tensor $T_{ij}$ becomes $T_{ij}'$. Well what if the change of basis isn't an orthogonal matrix? Then for any tensor $T_{ij}'\neq R_{ip}R_{jq}T_{pq}$ But if the change of basis matrix is orthogonal, $M_ij'=R_{ip}R_{jq}M_{pq}$ for any matrix! May I ask that an answer includes a concrete example. Thanks

I tried reading wikipedia and some other answers here, but they often use other definitions not covered in a physics course.

Comment: Yes, a rank-2 tensor is a matrix, but it is a lot more than that: a *tensor field* is a matrix defined at every point and the transformation laws it must obey have to do with covariant derivatives. I recommend Sean Carrolls  book about GR or any other favourite GR book of yours. Needless to say that these contain concrete examples. Maybe, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4201501/exist-contravariant-derivative/4202076#4202076) also helps.

Comment: Tensors are not matrices but are represented by them. Their transformations are physically relevant because it "suffices" to know the transformation matrices to directly know the tensor in the new coordinate system. Equations that are written with tensors are coordinate invariant, it is a very interesting feature for physics.

Comment: it means that it's time to buy a better book.

Comment: ... or read the availlable ones more carefully: a rank-2 tensor is *represented by* a matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is difficult, I will try to avoid mathematical definitions here. A tensor $T$ is, first and foremost, a *geometric* object. It lives in a space on its own and bears no reference to anything else.

When we choose basis vectors, the tensor $T$ can be expressed as a unique linear combination of the basis. In your example, it is
$$T=T_{kl} \mathbf{e}^k \otimes\mathbf{e}^l$$

The coefficients $T_{kl}$ are known as the *components* of $T$ in this particular basis. Now, let's choose another basis $\bar{\mathbf{e}}^i = M^i_j \mathbf{e}^j$ where $M$ is any invertible matrix. It must be true that we can also express $T$ as a linear combination of the new basis
$$T=\bar{T}_{ij} \bar{\mathbf{e}}^i \otimes \bar{\mathbf{e}}^j$$
where $\bar{T}$ are the new components. Substituting it into the above equation, we get
$$T=\bar{T}_{ij} \bar{\mathbf{e}}^i \otimes \bar{\mathbf{e}}^j = \bar{T}_{ij} M^i_k \mathbf{e}^k \otimes M^j_l \mathbf{e}^l = \bar{T}_{ij} M^i_k M^j_l \mathbf{e}^k \otimes \mathbf{e}^l$$
from which we see that $T_{kl} = \bar{T}_{ij} M^i_k M^j_l$ by comparing with our first equation. We have derived the tensor transformation law by requiring nothing other than the fact that $T$ itself remains unchanged. The only other condition needed is that the transformation matrix is invertible. You can also check that inverting the transformation gives
$$\bar{T}_{ij} = T_{kl}\left(M^{-1}\right)^k_i \left(M^{-1}\right)^l_j$$

This is very significant in physics because the laws of physics do not depend on the choice of coordinate system.

Comment: They are not geometric, they are algebraic. And that's exactly what you have shown yourself. Although certain tensors have geometric properties(Riemann), and some are only partly geometric because their basis are coordinate induced(EM tensor) and some have nothing whatsoever to do with geometry(quantum state of two or more particles). But they are all algebraic in the sense you explained above and more.

Comment: @RajatMondal I do not agree that they are not geometric. The modern formulation of tensors is usually done in Ricci calculus, which is strictly a topic in *differential geometry*. Tensors would be seen as a type of geometric quantity. Your disagreement with Vincent's seems like a difference in viewpoint, rather than anything incorrect in the answer.

Comment: @Eletie I gave an example of a tensor(used in physics) that has nothing to do with geometry. The quantum states of many particle systems are tensor products of the individual particle states. Obviously they can't be geometric(they are even infinite dimensional in most cases). Yet their "transformation laws" are exactly same as Vincent showed here.

Comment: @RajatMondal Hm ok, I guess the answer depends on the context then. Historically tensors are geometric quantities arising in differential geometry (Ricci calculus) and I think this is the context in which most people are usually talking about (i.e. a section of a vector bundle). I also think this is the most natural way to introduce where these transformation rules come from.

Comment: @RajatMondal While tensors are algebraic in mathematics, I was talking about them in the context of differential geometry (evident from the question tags), where they *do* have geometric meaning.

Comment: @VincentThacker Even in the context of GR, the Faraday tensor is only partly geometric. It has to do with them being totally antisymmetric, they are differential forms. Hence all the formulas in EM theory are in terms of exterior algebra which is well known to be the purely algebraic part of DG. Only thing they have to do with geometry is that they are defined on a manifold.

Comment: @RajatMondal I am not quite sure why you are arguing with me about this, but differential forms certainly have significant geometrical meaning, at least in this context.

Answer (score 1):

> May I ask that an answer includes a concrete example.

In physics, we actually consider **tensor fields** like the electromagnetic field tensor. To understand tensor fields, you first need some knowledge of multilinear algebra, manifolds and tangent spaces.

However, it is not difficult to see where your transformation rule originates: Given some finite-dimensional vector space, each basis defines an isomorphism between tensors and matrices and your formula is the transformstion rule for the matrices associated to the same tensor through different bases.

### Derivation of the transformation rule

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $I:=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then the **dual space**
$$V^*:=L(V,F)$$
is the set of all linear functions from $V$ to $F$. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be a basis of $V$, then $$v^1,\ldots,v^n\in V^*$$ is a basis of $\displaystyle{V^*}$ - the [dual basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis). It follows from the [universal property of the tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property) that
$$\{v^k\otimes v^l:k,l\in I\}\subset V^*\otimes V^*$$
is a basis of $\displaystyle{V^*\otimes V^*}$, the vector space of rank $2$ tensors mentioned in your question. That is, the function
\begin{align}
F^{n\times n}&\to V^*\otimes V^*\\
A&\mapsto A_{kl}\cdot v^k\otimes v^l
\end{align}
is a bijection, where $\displaystyle{F^{n\times n}}$ denotes the set of all $n\times n$-matrices with entries in $F$.

Now let $w_1,\ldots,w_n\in V$ be another basis and consider the matrix $R\in\displaystyle{F^{n\times n}}$ defined by
$$R^k{}_l:=v^k(w_l)$$
for all $k,l\in I$. Suppose $t\in\displaystyle{V^*\otimes V^*}$ and
$$t=T_{kl}\cdot v^k\otimes v^l={T'}_{kl}\cdot w^k\otimes w^l,$$
then it can be shown that
$${T'}_{ij}=R^k{}_iR^l{}_jT_{kl},$$
for all $i,j\in I$, which is your transformation rule.